# adding style to mat-option of mat-autocomplete

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I have this HTML [code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-with-selected-value-vx1uqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html)

```
<div style="width: 150px">
  <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Assignee" aria-label="Assignee" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
</div>
```

The default behaviour of `mat-option` is using

```
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis
```

1. I want to break the long sentence into next line rather than using `...` . The styling wont work :(
2. I also need to override the font which I tried also using below code, but it wont override

```
mat-option {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; // does not work
  }
```

[styling here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-autocomplete-with-selected-value-vx1uqg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.scss)

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
.mat-option{
  word-wrap:break-word !important;
  white-space:normal !important;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.mat-option-text{
  line-height:initial !important;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason why your stlying does not work is because the actual options are shown in a overlay which is placed in the `<body>`. Therefore the selector `component mat-option` cannot work, because the options are not placed in the component.

To override any styles that are in the `mat-option` you better address the class `.mat-option` and place it into the global `styles.scss`

```
.mat-option {
   font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif; // 
}
```

Comment: any help on the line break rather than `...` in it

Comment: sorry, that's a bit more styling for a short answer, you'll need to edit the behaviour of .mat-option and .mat-option-text together.

Comment: @User985614: doesn't `white-space: wrap; text-overflow: initial;` work?

Comment: Well then there's the line-height, option height, a lot of stuff going on. I'd suggest adding more space rather than trying to change material. Using the `panelWidth: string | number` input.