# Adding Style to mat-option of mat-autocomplete

Tags: html, css, angular

My `autocomplete-filter-example.html` file:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Assignee</mat-label>
    <input
      type="text"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option"
      >
        {{option.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

and `autocomplete-filter-example.css`

```
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}

.mat-option {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.mat-option-text {
  text-emphasis-color: red;
}
```

How can I get the css styles to apply to the `mat-option`? Also, how can I set the dropdown select list to be scrollable and only show one option at a time?

[Style Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w5meky-l2xu5u?file=src/app/autocomplete-display-example.css)

Tried to follow the top answer from [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67000746/adding-style-to-mat-option-of-mat-autocomplete) but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` to your component decorator:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./some.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
```

Comment: Does this only work if I add a custom class to the component? e.g. `class="test-class"`

Comment: If you define the styles you want in "some.component.scss" using `.test-class`, then any child components whose elements have that class will inherit the styling

Comment: Makes sense - is there any way to get it to work with `.mat-option`?

Comment: Yep! I would inspect the .mat-option element in your browser dev tools and use whatever selector the Material team used for styling, otherwise whatever you add will get ignored by precedence.

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" class = "test-class" classlist="test-class">
```

You can use ::ng-deep if you still want to do it in the component css file

```
::ng-deep .test-class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That works, but is there a way to do it without using `ng-deep`?

Comment: @g999 yes. See my answer. `ng-deep` should be avoided. It's deprecated and will soon be removed: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep